# How to allow users to upload large images (>5 gb) to a Drupal site?

Tags: drupal, file-upload, ftp, drupal-7

I am working on a Drupal site and we need users to be able to upload 5-10 GB files to the site. Right now, we give users FTP credentials, but it's a pretty poor experience having to make them download an FTP client and walking them through that process.

I've searched for other options, but haven't had any luck. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, please see this post on how to up the file upload size limits in Drupal/PHP : https://drupal.org/node/97193

Answer (score 1):

You may try **File Resumable Upload**:
https://www.drupal.org/project/file_resup

Answer (score 0):

Our server is running PHP 5.3.3 and I had some trouble enabling very large file uploads (greater than 4GB). What worked was:

```
max_input_time = 3600 
upload_max_filesize = 0
post_max_size = 16G
```

Furthermore, if your temporary directory is on a different filesystem than the final destination of your file, the file copy time may be too long. Adjust max_execution_time too:

```
max_execution_time = 3600
```